# Is Adding or Subtracting From a DATETIME Guaranteed to be Number of Days?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime, language-lawyer

I was reviewing some older stored procedures that we have, and encountered something that, while I know it works, had me thinking about how much I can assume that it would work.

The code is subtracting seven days from the current date, and doing it like so:

```
Select GetDate() - 7
```

Now, before I ask this question, I want to be perfectly clear:  yes, I completely understand that the correct way to do this would be with the following:

```
Select DateAdd(Day, -7, GetDate())
```

That, however, is *not* my question.

My question is, can I safely make the assumption that (in *all* cases), when adding or subtracting a numerical value from a `DATETIME` datatype, it will *always* add or remove in multiples of days?

Will `GetDate() - 7` *always* remove seven *days*?

Can there *ever* be a way, via any possible scenario (configurations, region, collation, gremlins, whatever...) that doing `GetDate() - 7` will result in some other date component (e.g. `Hour`, `Minute`, `Microsecond`, etc.) being subtracted instead of `Day`s?

Comment: As an aside its worth noting that any function/column returning a date/datetime2 such as sysdatetime/sysutcdatetime will fail if you attempt to use an arithmetical operator, so the dateadd approach can be a good habit to form.

Comment: @AlexK. Absolutely, and the `DATE` datatype also does not support it.  This question was more sprung about by the concern of needing to go back and update these older stored procedures.  But yes, I absolutely agree that using `DATEADD` is the approach that should be used, regardless of the consistency of adding or subtracting from a `DATETIME`.

Comment: It is considered a bad habit (and likely to break in the future). I would suggest not doing that. Seems that Aaron Bertrand agrees...see the first part of his post here. https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is guaranteed. The behavior of the `-` operator between a datetime and an integer is well defined, and won't be altered by any configuration.

Comment: That was my suspicion as well, but do you happen to have a link to documentation that states that?

Comment: I remember reading about how this goes back to sysbase and how datetime is stored. Martin smith has something on it somewhere but i can't find it @Siyual

Comment: @Siyual here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/subtract-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#b-using-date-subtraction

Comment: @Mureinik perfect!  Thank you!